# How to apply lsp quick fix in sublime text using a shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, sublime-text

This an example of a angular attribute directive. `@HostListener` is not imported in the class.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appDropdown]",
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  constructor(
    private readonly elementRef: ElementRef,
    private readonly renderer2: Renderer2,
  ) {}

  @HostBinding("class.open") isOpen = false;

  @HostListener("click")
  toggle() {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    const isOpen = element.classList.contains("open");

    // element.classList.toggle("open", !isOpen);

    if (isOpen) {
      this.renderer2.removeClass(element, "open");

      return;
    }

    this.renderer2.addClass(element, "open");

    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

I get a couple of chooses from lsp quik fix. How can I apply a lsp quick fix using some shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LSP, they call it "Code Actions". From [their documentation](https://lsp.sublimetext.io/features/#code-actions):

> Code Actions are an umbrella term for "Quick Fixes" and "Refactorings". They are actions that change the file (or more than one file) to resolve a diagnostic or apply a standard refactor technique. For instance, extracting a block of code into a separate method is usually called "Extract Method" and is a "Refactoring". Whereas "add a missing semicolon" would resolve a diagnostic that warns about a missing semicolon.

You can set a shortcut by:

1. Opening `Preferences: LSP Key Bindings` (ctrl+shift+p, LSP Key Bindings)
2. Search for `Run Code Action`, copy the block to the right panel, and uncomment
3. Assign a shortcut. I went for `ctrl+.`, which mimics VSCode:

```
    // Run Code Action
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+."],
        "command": "lsp_code_actions",
        "context": [{"key": "lsp.session_with_capability", "operand": "codeActionProvider"}]
    },
```